# Making object disposal less stochastic

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm working on an older system written in VB.NET, and it keeps throwing an exception when the application is closing because it's trying to access a disposed object. It occurs in a delegate that sets the text of a Label on the UI thread from another thread:

```
Private Sub SetWeightText_ThreadSafe(ByVal theLabel As Label, ByVal value As String)
    If Not Me.IsDisposed AndAlso Not Me.Disposing Then
        If theLabel.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim theDelegate As New SetWeightText_Del(AddressOf SetWeightText_ThreadSafe)
           'Exception here:
            Me.Invoke(theDelegate, New Object() {theLabel, value}) 
        Else
            theLabel.Text = value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The exception occurs at the line marked above, where the delegate is invoked. When the debugger stops here, the exception shows that the object (`Me`) has been disposed, and sure enough, `Me.Disposing` has become true, obviously sometime between that initial `if` statement, and the delegate's invocation.

The exception is `ObjectDisposedException was unhandled by user code`. I understand I could probably just wrap the whole thing in a `Try..Catch` with an empty handler and be done with it, but I'd rather prevent the issue altogether.

And this occurs *every* time. How do I avoid this?

Comment: How is it `stochastic` if it happens every time? It sounds like you closed a form and this is trying to access it afterwards.

Comment: Are you sure the window still got a handle? If not `InvokeRequired` will return `False`.

Comment: @OneFineDay Yes I suppose I used the wrong word there, I was mainly referring to the fact that `Disposing` was returning `False` and then two lines later it is now `True`. @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I don't think that is an issue, the exception occurs when `InvokeRequired` has already evaluated to `True`. Furthermore this method is only called from the other thread, so even evaluating `InvokeRequired` appears to be more of a sanity check than anything else.

Comment: @helrich Why do you check if the `theLabel` requires invoke and not the form? Change `If theLabel.InvokeRequired Then` to `If Me.InvokeRequired Then` and `Else` to `ElseIf (Me.Handle <> IntPtr.Zero) Then`.